# Direct eBook-speaker to a bluetooth speaker

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, alsa

### Problem

Can't direct eBook-speaker to use different audio hardware. It goes to my internal speakers/headphone jack, but won't use a bluetooth speaker. Prefs are set in `./eBook-speaker.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <eBook-speaker>
    <prefs sound_dev="hw:0" ocr_language=""/>
    ...
```

But when I try to change the value of `sound_dev` I just get an error: `hw:0: Invalid argument`.

### Context

I've got an issue with my Lenovo T510 laptop speakers. They work on startup, then stop working. After that, headphones plugged into the jack work fine, and bluetooth speakers work fine, but the built-in speakers don't work. I've gone through all of the sound troubleshooting [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure), but haven't been able to get it to work. Seems to work fine when I disable pulseaudio and use only alsa, but for the most part I'm getting around it by using a bluetooth speaker. I want to set eBook-speaker to read to me while I'm walking around the room, so I need to direct output to the bluetooth speakers.

### Solution

I still don't have a solution for the internal speakers not working, but the developer of eBook-speaker responded to my query and suggested that I direct the application to use 'default' for audio device.

```
eBook-speaker -d default your_book.epub
```

When I fire it up this way, eBook-speaker doesn't quit when I change the volume setting or switch between audio devices, and playback with the Bluetooth speakers works just fine.

Comment: Does the error message really say "hw:0" when you have changed it to something else?

Comment: No, it just outputs the same error with the new hardware designation.  `hw:1: Invalid argument` and so forth. Makes no difference what I change it to.